# Why does the definition of Array.map in Scala is "throw new Error()"

Tags: scala

The source code of `map` for [Array](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_7_final/src/library/scala/Array.scala) is:

```
override def map[B](f: A => B): Array[B] = throw new Error()
```

But the following works:

```
val name : Array[String]= new Array(1)
name(0)="Oscar"
val x = name.map {  ( s: String ) => s.toUpperCase }
// returns: x: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(OSCAR)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, when you see `throw new Error()` in the source code of a library class, it represents a point where the compiler is intervening and implementing the method by bridging to a facility of the platform (remember this could be Java or .NET).

The [Array SID](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/7) explains how arrays used to be treated in Scala 2.7.x, and how they have changed in 2.8. The compiler used to magically convert the object to a `BoxedArray` if you called `map`.

In 2.8, integration of Arrays into the Scala collections framework is largely handled with use of normal langauges features -- implicit conversions from `Array[T]` to `WrappedArray[T]` or `ArraySeq[T]`, depending on the context, and implicit parameters of type `Manifest[T]` to support creation of arrays of a generic type `T`. Array [indexing](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L528), [length](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L512) and [update](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L547) still appear as `throw new Error()`. `Array#map` no longer exists, instead you find this on `WrappedArray` and `ArraySeq` as a regular method.

**UPDATE**

If you're interested to know this compiler magic is defined, take a look at Scala 2.8 incarnation of [Cleanup.scala](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/CleanUp.scala?rev=21919#L414).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's just dummy code, as Scala arrays are really Java ones.

Comment: similar to "native" ? In java, I mean, like... *Hey, don't worry, I know what to do underneath?*

Comment: That'd be my guess, though I don't know for sure.